# Computing the invariant distribution of a two-step Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

I'm having trouble with this problem.

> Let $X=(X_n)$ be a Markov chain on a countable state space $S$ with transition matrix $P$ and invariant distribution $\pi$. Let $Y=(Y_n)$ be defined by $Y_n = (X_n, X_{n+1})$. I want to compute the invariant distribution $\nu$ of $Y$.

It was easy to show that $Y$ is in fact a Markov chain. For the invariant distribution, these are my thoughts so far:

If $Q$ is the transition matrix of $Y$, then we need $\nu Q = \nu$ to hold, i.e.
$$\nu(r,s) = \sum_{(i,j)\in S \times S} \nu(i,j,) q\big((i,j),(r,s)\big).$$
By definition of $Y$ we also have
$$\mathbb P\big(Y_{n+1}=(r,s) \vert Y_n=(i,j)\big)
=\mathbb P\big(X_{x+1}=r, X_{n+2}=s \vert X_n=i, X_{n+1}=j\big)
=\mathbb P\big(X_{n+2}=s \vert X_{n+1}=j\big)$$
So we have $q((i,j),(r,s)) = p(j,s)$ and I need to find a distribution $\nu$ such that
$$\nu(r,s) = \sum_{(i,j)\in S \times S} \nu(i,j,) p(j,s).$$

From here I was lacking a systematic approach because of that nasty double sum. But since $Y$ is defined in terms of $X$ and we know the invariant distribution $\pi$ of $X$, it makes sense that $\nu$ should be given in terms of $\pi$ (and $P$ as I figured after some trying).

So I basically just tried to choose $\nu(r,s)$ in a way that gets rid of those sums. Turns out that $\nu(r,s) = \pi(r) p(r,s)$ does the trick and I guess it also makes kind of sense intuitively. Howver, plugging it into the definition of an invariant distribution yields

$$\sum_{i,j \in S} \pi(i) p(i,j) p(j,s)
=\sum_j \sum_i \pi(i) p(i,j) p(j,s)
=\sum_j \pi(j) p(j,s)
=\pi(s).$$

But here I'm confused: This term should give back the stationary distribtion $\pi(r) p(r,s)$, shouldn't it?

Comment: Try $$\nu(r,s)=\pi(r)P(r,s)$$

Comment: But that's what I did. :)

Comment: Then you might have missed that $$q((i,j),(r,s)) = p(j,s)\mathbf 1_{j=r}$$ hence $$(\nu q)(r,s)=\sum_{(i,j)}\nu(i,j)q((i,j);(r,s))=\sum_i\pi(i)p(i,r)p(r,s)=\ldots$$

Comment: Indeed, I missed the indicator function. That solves the problem. Thank you! (Maybe you want to post your comment as an answer, so I can check the question?)

Comment: Or you can post an answer yourself, summarizing and/or expanding what we said?

Comment: I just tried to work out the answer in all details, but something isn't quite clear to me, yet: In order to characterise $q((i,j),(r,s))$, I come across the term $\mathbb P(X_{n+1}=r, X_{n+2}=s \vert X_n = i, X_{n+1}=j)$. We can drop $X_n=i$ because of the Markov property. But how can I write this as $\mathbb P(X_{n+2}=s, j=r \vert X_{n+1}=j)$? Is $\{j=r\}$ even an event?

Comment: Rather try $P(X_{n+1}=r,X_{n+2}=s\mid X_{n+1}=j)=0$ for every $r\ne j$ and $=P(X_{n+2}=s\mid X_{n+1}=j)$ for $r=j$.